# data not passing when running doInBackground method within for loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have some pics to upload to the ftp server and I am using Asynctask for it.The images need to be sent to multiple host so I am using a for loop.The data to be passed is very well being fetched by the constructor but the doInBackground method is not running which was earlier running very well without the for loop and the additional data apart from the String **filePathName** that I am trying to pass in now in doInBackground.please help me

```
class uploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public uploadTask(String filePathName,String host_2,String user_2,String pass_2)
    {
        filePath=filePathName;
        host_1=host_2;
        user_1=user_2;
        pass_1=pass_2;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"FTP DATA RECEIVING:"+"HOST:"+host_2+" USERNAME:"+user_2+" PASS:"+pass_2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //hostName=host;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entered Do in Background Method to upload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ftp_host = "ftp.photoshelter.com";//This is not the correct way. Supposed to get from Backendless table
            ftp_username = "brytest";//This is not the correct way. Supposed to get from Backendless table
            ftp_password = "passtest";//This is not the correct way. Supposed to get from Backendless table
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"HOST:"+ftp_host+" USERNAME:"+ftp_username+" PASS:"+ftp_password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            news_agency = "news agency";
            easyFTP ftp = new easyFTP();
            ftp.connect(ftp_host, ftp_username, ftp_password);
            status = ftp.setWorkingDirectory("mem/images"); // if User say provided any Destination then Set it , otherwise
            // Upload will be stored on Default /root level on server
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageTimeStamped = ftp_username + "_" + timeStamp + ".png";
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFileLocation);
            //addPhotoGrapherInfo();

            ftp.uploadFile(is, imageTimeStamped);
            System.out.println("Successfull ftp upload to " + ftp_host);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Photo uploading by ftp to " + ftp_host, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //}
                //reset booleans
                //cameraPicTaken = false;
                //galleryImageSelected = false;
                //System.out.println("reset cameraPicTaken and galleryImageSelected");
           // }
                return new String("Upload Successful");
        }catch (Exception e){
            String t="Failure : " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

my onClickListener with for loop

```
 if(cameraPicTaken || galleryImageSelected) {
                Toast.makeText(SubmitActivity.this,"Image Location is:"+ imageFileLocation,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //addPhotoGrapherInfo();
                for(int i=0;i<Common.selectedHostArray.size();i++) {
                    uploadFile(imageFileLocation,Common.selectedHostArray.get(i),Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(i),Common.selectedPasswordArray.get(i));
                }
                cameraPicTaken = false;
                galleryImageSelected = false;
            }
```

funnction called in onClick

```
public void uploadFile(String filePath,String host_1,String user_1,String pass_1)
{
    if(cameraPicTaken == true) {
        System.out.println("camera photo start upload");
        //for(int i=0;i<Common.selectedHostArray.size();i++) {
            //host_1=Common.selectedHostArray.get(i);
            //user_1=Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(i);
            //pass_1=Common.selectedPasswordArray.get(i);
            //host_1="ftp.photoshelter.com";
            //user_1="brytest";
            //pass_1="passtest";
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"FTP DATA PASSING:"+"HOST:"+host_1+" USERNAME:"+user_1+" PASS:"+pass_1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new uploadTask(filePath,host_1,user_1,pass_1).execute();
       // }
        //cameraPicTaken = false;
        //galleryImageSelected = false;
        System.out.println("reset cameraPicTaken and galleryImageSelected");
      //cameraPicTaken = false;

    }
    if(galleryImageSelected == true){
        System.out.println("gallery image start upload");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"FTP DATA PASSING:"+"HOST:"+host_1+" USERNAME:"+user_1+" PASS:"+pass_1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new uploadTask(filePath,host_1,user_1,pass_1).execute();
        //new uploadTask(filePat)h.execute();
        //galleryImageSelected = false;
    }

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Photo uploading by ftp to photoshelter.com" /*+ news_agency*/, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: are you creating multiple uploadTasks in a for loop? Please show the calling code if possible.

Comment: where is the for loop?

Comment: I have edited my question with my OnClick and called function.please check it

Comment: @Jon Yes I need to call uploadTasks multiple times

Comment: By default, your async tasks are running serially. Task #2 shouldn't kick off until `doInBackground` from Task#1 finishes. If you wait, do the tasks still not run?

Comment: I can very well see the Toast 'FTP DATA RECEIVING' in the constructor but I cannot see the Toast 'Entered doInBackground'

Comment: Earlier I had only 1 String filePathName.Now I have 3 more.So do i have to put some additional parameters in doInBackground(String.....params)?

Comment: Look at your stacktrace; You're trying to Toast on a non ui thread and I'm pretty sure that's crashing and getting caught in your try/catch

Comment: You should honestly be putting all of your params in the argument `String... params` instead of the constructor. Asynctask was built in a way such that the params are passed between threads efficiently and safely. The way you currently have it, your variables could potentially have stale data if they aren't marked as `volatile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to perform a UI command on a background thread (Toast). This is causing your background tasks to fail early. Since your background tasks catch their own errors, they fail silently.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        // you can't Toast on a background thread, this should throw an exception
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entered Do in Background Method to upload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ...
    }catch (Exception e){
        // your Toast exception is getting caught silently here
        String t="Failure : " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        return t;
    }
}
```

By the way, the try/catch on everything is not a good practice. You end up with a ton of silent failures leaving you scratching your head and asking why things aren't working.

Comment: so ur asking me to remove try catch?should I do that?

Comment: I tried that but removing try catch puts a red line below error below ftp.connect(......) indictaing unhandled exception

Comment: To get your tasks to run, remove your Toast. You cannot do UI work in `doInBackground`. My suggestion about the try/catch are just about good programming practice. Usually, you want to catch only the *lines you expect can fail*. So when unexpected failures (like this toast failure) occurs, it will be obvious :)

Comment: If you're using `Toast` to debug, then instead I suggest using `Log.d(...)` and reading your data from logcat. `Log.d(...)` is safe to run on any thread.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that it helps the next person too :)